# Flow Path length

Tags: qgis, saga, flow

I'm a student and pretty much new to QGIS, GRASS and SAGA tools.

I'm trying to calculate the longest flow path length using SAGA "flow path length" module in Qgis. Using the default parameters:

[image]

I've added the elevation raster in input but after running the algorithm gives me this message:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details
```

It looks like there's a problem with the projection fo my elevation raster but I don't know how to solve it.

Here's the log:

```
  Avvio dell'algoritmo Flow path length...
io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "/var/folders/gj/24tjnl3d5q1cbmf8qrzp5l080000gp/T/processing910e7d22ea2041cc939e7488099b5565/92672e01a5cf41ee821f071e6242f7a5/dtm5x5reg.sgrd" -FILES "/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI_ELABORATO/Analisi Idrologica/Area contribuente/AreaContribuente/AreaDTM5x5/dtm5x5reg.asc"
ta_hydrology "Flow Path Length" -ELEVATION "/var/folders/gj/24tjnl3d5q1cbmf8qrzp5l080000gp/T/processing910e7d22ea2041cc939e7488099b5565/92672e01a5cf41ee821f071e6242f7a5/dtm5x5reg.sgrd" -SEEDS_ONLY false -METHOD 0 -CONVERGENCE 1.1 -LENGTH "/var/folders/gj/24tjnl3d5q1cbmf8qrzp5l080000gp/T/processing910e7d22ea2041cc939e7488099b5565/3df24309d1b44b6a9b92e95176e61762/LENGTH.sdat"
/Users/macbook/.qgis2//processing/saga_batch_job.sh: line 3: 35670 Segmentation fault: 11 saga_cmd io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "/var/folders/gj/24tjnl3d5q1cbmf8qrzp5l080000gp/T/processing910e7d22ea2041cc939e7488099b5565/92672e01a5cf41ee821f071e6242f7a5/dtm5x5reg.sgrd" -FILES "/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI_ELABORATO/Analisi Idrologica/Area contribuente/AreaContribuente/AreaDTM5x5/dtm5x5reg.asc"
Error: input file [/var/folders/gj/24tjnl3d5q1cbmf8qrzp5l080000gp/T/processing910e7d22ea2041cc939e7488099b5565/92672e01a5cf41ee821f071e6242f7a5/dtm5x5reg.sgrd]
Error: Elevation
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.2.3

____________________________
library path: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/saga/
library name: libta_hydrology
library : Hydrology
tool : Flow Path Length
author : (c) 2005 by O.Conrad
____________________________

Load grid: /var/folders/gj/24tjnl3d5q1cbmf8qrzp5l080000gp/T/processing910e7d22ea2041cc939e7488099b5565/92672e01a5cf41ee821f071e6242f7a5/dtm5x5reg.sgrd...
failed

Usage: saga_cmd ta_hydrology 6 [-ELEVATION ] [-SEED ] [-LENGTH ] [-SEEDS_ONLY ] [-METHOD ] [-CONVERGENCE ]
-ELEVATION: Elevation
Grid (input)
-SEED: Seeds
Grid (optional input)
-LENGTH: Flow Path Length
Grid (output)
-SEEDS_ONLY: Seeds Only
Boolean
Default: 0
-METHOD: Flow Routing Algorithm
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] Deterministic 8 (D8)
[1] Multiple Flow Direction (FD8)
Default: 1
-CONVERGENCE: Convergence (FD8)
Floating point
Minimum: 0.000000
Default: 1.100000
Converting outputs

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details
```

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: @Joseph I'm using 2.14.7-Essen

Comment: `NoneType` is the type for the `None` object and it represents the absence of a value. This means that the tool you are using failed to read your input raster. Can you provide it or a sample of it? If of interest, even your input parameters, thanks!

Comment: @HowToInQGIS I uploaded it here: https://infinit.io/_/XPYjrfG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your raster and the default input parameters:

[image]

it gives me a raster with only `nan`values (I think because I'm requesting something from an additional input layer that is not specified):

Instead, unchecking the `Seeds only` option, it seems to work:

[image]

but I don't know what this output means and if it is a correct result.

Comment: The result you showed is perfect. But unfortunately even unchecking the 'seeds only' option the massage still comes out.

Comment: I have seen that the raster is from Italy, so even the CRS I used (EPSG:32632, WGS84/UTM zone 32N) should be correct. I didn't do any other particular operation: I loaded the raster in **the Layers Panel** and I ran the tool under the CRS above mentioned. Try to set it as the Project CRS (but I think it shouldn't is the origin of your error).
Can you retrieve a log?

Comment: log in the original question

Comment: Try this: firstly, copy&paste your raster to the Desktop; then, load the raster from the Desktop and run the tool without writing `FlowPaths` in the output path (don't write anything, as in my attachment of the dialog). Does it change something?

Comment: Therefore, from the log I read `dtm5x5reg.asc`, but your provided a `.tif` file.

Comment: Loading the .asc from desktop works! Thank you! Why doesn't it work using my project home folder though?

Comment: Thanks to you for reporting the log, it helped to retrieve the problem. In your case, it was a classical path error: the tool should work wherever your file is stored, but be sure to avoid any blank space because it could compromise the result (as you have seen). For example, there is a folder named `Area contribuente`: try to rename it in `Area_contribuente` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately even writing Area_contribuente doesn't work. But loading the raster from the desktop work fine!

Comment: There is also `Analisi Idrologica` with a blank space. If the tool will not work even modifying this folder, it is probably due to a very "long" file path. Let me know if it works with these changes.